# Is there a REST api to create a channel in Agora Web sdk?

Tags: agora.io

I'm trying to integrate our web app with voice/video call feature by using Agora. I have read the documentation on their side, but I have not found any rest api for web sdk to create channel. Basically, when a user joins a channel, we have to pass in the app id, token, and channel name. I know that we can create channel in agora dashboard, but I'm looking for a dynamic way, where we can trigger a REST api to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How do you create channel in dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy your own [token server](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token_server), that will give you the token based on a channel name and uid.

Here's a [pre-built server](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-token-service) that you can deploy to Heroku in 2 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to build a node js to generate agora io token. It is hosted in heroku. The source code can be found here:
`https://github.com/Hoang-Minh/partie-agora-token-generator`

Here are the endpoint that you can call to generate a token:

`api/agora/rtcToken/:tokenType` where

- tokenType can be either `uid` or `account`, depends on what you need.
- The default expiration time that I have is 24 hours.